# How to I make code in JS case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, case-insensitive

Ok so here’s an example of my code: `if (message.content.startsWith("k beg")) {`

Basically, the code will work but the user must type in exactly **"k beg"** all lowercase. I want the code to be case insensitive for example **(K bEg)**, AND the message content should be just the input, so **"k beg"** shouldn’t trigger when it's in the middle of a sentence.

One of my major points though is to make it case insensitive, so if anyone can help with just that, I’ll be happy. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just lowercase the message first:

```
message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("k beg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform the text to lower or to upper case before checking

```
message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("k beg")

// or

message.content.toUpperCase().startsWith("K BEG")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(input) {
  return /^[ \t]*k[ \t]+beg/i.test(input)
}

console.log(test('k beg'))
console.log(test('K BEG'))
console.log(test('k    BeG'))
console.log(test('  k BeG'))
console.log(test('any k beg')) // false
```